# IPA transported to App Store Connect isn't showing on appStore connect

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-developer

I have just updated an app for iOS/iPadOS. The .ipa file is ready to upload to my App Store Connect entry for the app for first time.

I have copied the .ipa file to the Mac Mini, started the Transporter (v 1.2.4) and dragged my .ipa file onto the Transporter. I received a message saying the file was successfully uploaded.

Many hours later (16+), this build still hasn't appeared in the App Store Connect entry for the app so that I can submit it for review. What have I missed.

Thanks in advance!

I also tried to do this by xcode but same issue.

Comment: If there was a problem processing the build then you will receive an email.  Check your spam folder if you can't find it.

Comment: not receiving any email also check spam folder but nothing there.

Comment: Have you checked the TestFlight section - maybe your version number doesn't match the version you have in your App Store record.

Comment: Yeah, I checked this many times but there is nothing. I also tried to contact apple support but no response received yet.